# How do you make videos like this one?

Tags: video, animation

Other than drawing skills, what software does one need to make videos like this one?

http://www.dunnhumby.com/in/about-us-what-we-do

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable, you will need to provide your OS and what software you already have or are familiar with.  Also, you will need to give a better idea of exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In the year 2016, that link does not go anywhere that shows a video.  Can you provide a Youtube link?

Comment: It was one of those videos where someone really quickly draws up each they are talking about as they get to it, and then move on to the next drawing when they move to the next sentence. I'll try and find something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like it is a combination of traditional hand animation or possibly Flash or Illustrator combined with After Effects for compositing and camera motion.  The images appear to use a Draw On style followed by an animated wipe to remove them.  This is then overlaid over the background and camera motion is added by panning and zooming the entire image.